# How to pass array in URLs as parameter in Promise.all

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express, promise

How can I pass array of `url_user` as a parameter in Promise.all?

I use Node.js and Express.

```
url_project = 'https://api.projects'
url_user = [
   'https://api.users/1',
   'https://api.users/2',
   'https://api.users/3',
   'https://api.users/4',
   'https://api.users/5',
   'https://api.users/6'
]
```

**index.js**

```
<div>
   <%= projectsApi.id %>
   <% for (var i = 0; i < usersApi.length; i++) { %>
        <%= usersApi[i].id %>
   <% } %>
</div>
```

**server.js**

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

Promise
     .all([rp({uri: url_project, json:true}), rp({uri: url_user, json:true})]) //This where I want to edit
     .then(([projectsApi, usersApi]) => {
         res.render('index', {projectsApi, usersApi});
     }).catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
         res.sendStatus(500);
     });
```

When I put `Promise.all([rp({uri: url_project, json:true}), rp({uri: url_user[0], json:true})])`, it works since `url_user[0]` is not an array.

However I want to pass all datas in the array `url_user`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
url_project = 'https://api.projects'

url_user = [
   'https://api.users/1',
   'https://api.users/2',
   'https://api.users/3',
   'https://api.users/4',
   'https://api.users/5',
   'https://api.users/6'
]

const promises = [
  rp({uri: url_project, json:true}),
  ...url_user.map(value => rp({uri: value, json:true})
];

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(values => {
    console.log(values);
    // Adjust your response
    // ...
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. When I print out `console.log(usersApi)`, it showed different datas of JSON which was url information, but url_user datas.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const url_project = 'https://api.projects'

const url_user = [
   'https://api.users/1',
   'https://api.users/2',
   'https://api.users/3',
   'https://api.users/4',
   'https://api.users/5',
   'https://api.users/6'
]

const promises = [
  rp({uri: url_project, json:true}),
  ...url_user.map(value => rp({uri: value, json:true})
];

Promise
     .all(promises)
     .then(([projectsApi, ...usersApi]) => {
         res.render('index', {projectsApi, usersApi});
     }).catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
         res.sendStatus(500);
     });
```

Let me know if there are any issues.

Comment: When I print out `console.log(usersApi)`, it showed different datas of JSON which was url information, but url_user datas.

Comment: Can you show me the output of `console.log(usersApi)`, or at least the structure of the response?

Comment: `url : { [...] },
method : "GET",
headers : {
accept : "application/json"
} ...`

Comment: For additional context, what's the output of `console.log(projectsApi)`?

Comment: Hmm, weird, it's supposed to work. Can you show me your actual code?

Comment: Actually, could you please complete this code? `.then(([projectsApi, ...usersApi]) => {`

Comment: `.then(([projectsApi, ...usersApi]) => {
         res.render('index', {projectsApi, usersApi});
     }).catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
         res.sendStatus(500);
     });`

If it still doesn't work, it'll be helpful to post the other parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

CodeBlock:

```js
const rp = require('request-promise');
const _ = require('lodash'); //lodash is awesome, otherwise u can use JS map/concat

const projectUrl = 'https://api.projects';

const userUrls = [
  'https://api.users/1',
  ...,
  ...,
];

const promises =  
  _(projectUrl)
    .concat(userUrls)
    .map((requestUrl) -> rp({uri: requestUrl, json:true}))
    .value()

await Promise
  .all(promises)      
  .then((results) => {
    res.render('index', {projectsApi: results.shift(), usersApi: ...results});
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  });
```

Explanation:

```
Steps:
 - Get all requests together
 - Map over each using lodash or js map to get promises
 - Execute them together
 - Since project_url is the first request the result is the first item in array
 - Spread the reset of the result to get user results
```

Comment: Thank you. How could I finish this part of code? `res.render('index', {projectsApi: results.shift(), usersApi: ...results});`

Comment: what is the response structure?
Probably, JSON.stringify the result and paste the result

Comment: url : { [...] }, method : "GET", headers : { accept : "application/json" } ...